# Copying string from web scraper into csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dictionary

I am trying to make a web scraper that takes WWII speeches and places them into a CSV file. I want the columns to be: Speech, Speaker, Year. I am trying to add the speech text that I scraped from a website under the speech column but it is not working. I want the years to be 1939 - 45 and the Speaker to be the same for each one (since I only have Hitler's speeches from this website), but it is not working. I am not sure if it would be easier to place this all into a dictionary first and then place it into a CSV as a dataframe, or if I should write it directly into a CSV file.

```
main_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(main_page).read()
main_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(main_sauce, 'lxml')
list_html_links =driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
list_links = []
for i in list_html_links:
    list_links.append((i.get_attribute('href')))
driver.quit()
counter = 0
jsin = 0
string_list = np.array([])
mystring = ""
for j in list_links:
    if 26 <= counter < 47:
        if counter not in [29, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 43, 45]:
            sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(j).read()
            soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
            for a in soup.find_all('a'):
                a.extract()
            for paragraph in soup.body.find_all('p'):
                mystring += paragraph.text
            string_list[jsin] = mystring
            jsin += 1
    mystring = ""
    counter +=1
for speech in string_list:
    speech_dict = {'Speeches': string_list[speech], 
'Speaker': 'Adolf Hitler', 'Year': '1939-45'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas Data frame to make things easier..

```
Import pandas as pd

data_list = []
for speech in string_list:
    speech_dict = {'Speeches': string_list, 
    'Speaker': 'Adolf Hitler', 'Year': '1939-45'}
    data_list.append(speech_dict)
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
```